# A code that returns the partial permutations on {1,2,...,n}

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation

A partial permutation is a bijective partial function. A partial function is a map from a subset of {1,2,...,n} into {1,2,...,n}.

I want a list of the matrix representations of all the partial permutations on {1,2,...,n}.  For example the code below returns the desired matrices for n <=4.  I would be happy to see the matrices for some larger values of n.

```
nn = 2;
ppQ[list_] := Apply[And, Table[Count[list[[i]], 1] <= 1 && Count[Transpose[list][[i]], 1] <= 1, {i, 1, Length[list]}]];
ppnn = Select[Tuples[Tuples[{0, 1}, nn], nn], ppQ[#] &]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[partialPermMatrices1]

 partialPermMatrices1[n_] := Module[{im = PadRight[IdentityMatrix[n], {n + 1, n}], 
  p = Permutations[Join[ConstantArray[n + 1, n], Range@n], {n}]}, 
  Sort @ Map[Extract[im, List /@ #] &] @ p]
```

***Examples:***

```
MatrixForm /@ partialPermMatrices1[2] // Row
```

[image]

```
MatrixForm /@ partialPermMatrices1[3] // Multicolumn[#, 7] &
```

[image]

```
Length[partialPermMatrices1 @ #] & /@ Range[8]
```

> ```
> {2, 7, 34, 209, 1546, 13327, 130922, 1441729}
> ```

An alternative (slower) method:

```
ClearAll[partialPermMatrices2]

partialPermMatrices2[n_] := Module[
  {f = Map[Through @* 
        (MapAt[ConstantArray[0, n] &, List /@ #] & /@ Subsets[Range @ n])], 
   im = Sort @ Permute[IdentityMatrix @ n, SymmetricGroup @ n]}, 
 Union @@ f @ im]
```

And a variation on OP's method using `Tuples` + `Select`:

```
ClearAll[partialPermMatrices3]
partialPermMatrices3[n_] := Select[Max[{Total @ #, Total[#, {2}]}] <= 1 &]@
 Tuples[{0, 1}, {n, n}]

(partialPermMatrices1[#] == 
   partialPermMatrices2[#] == 
     partialPermMatrices3[#]) & /@ Range[4]
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True}
> ```

Although `partialPermMatrices3` faster than OP's method it is much slower than `partialPermMatrices1`.

**An aside:** If we want only the partial permutations, we can use a variant of `partialPermMatrices` as follows:

```
ClearAll[partialPerms]
partialPerms[n_] := Permutations[Join[ConstantArray[♢, n], Range @ n], {n}]
```

***Examples:***

```
Multicolumn[Row /@ #, Min[Length@#, 12], Appearance -> "Horizontal", 
    Dividers -> All] & /@ (partialPerms[#] & /@ Range[4]) // Column
```

[image]

Comment: This is great!  Thank you.   I wrote a code that counts the number of commuting pairs of partial permutations and submitted to OEIS.  Is it OK to incorporate  your code into mine.  I can list you as co-author of the code  if you wanted.

Comment: @geoffrey, thank you so much for the generous offer. If needed/feasible you can link to this answer as reference.